# Replace '-' char using sed

Tags: unix, sed, find-and-replace

I have a text file, quite similar to this one:

```
    JACK     BLACK 123456   -1245368 - 
 BRIDGET       RED   1245     548425 + 
  JOHNNY    HOMUSS  55482      -4325 -
```

I wanted to use a `sed` command to replace the `-` character with a blank `' '` one in the last number section, some my output would be:

```
    JACK     BLACK 123456    1245368 - 
 BRIDGET       RED   1245     548425 + 
  JOHNNY    HOMUSS  55482       4325 -
```

I'm using this one, but of course is not working, because it replaces all the `-` chars in the textfile:

```
sed -e 's/-/ /g' old.out > new.out
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is pretty much in a similar format, i.e. only the last column containing digits might contain a `-`, then you could simply remove `g` from the `sed` expression:

```
sed 's/-/ /g' old.out > new.out
```

If you wanted to remove `-` from all numbers in the file, you could check if `-` is followed by a digit:

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\)/ \1/' old.out > new.out
```

If you want to remove `-` from the last column that contains a digit, you could say:

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\([^0-9]*\)$/ \1\2/' old.out > new.out
```